# Implement function without name in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I'm trying to implement a function without name like this:

```
interface I {
    (name: string): void;    
}

class C implements I {
    (name: string):void { }
}
```

I want to use C like this, but it doesn't work:

```
C("test");
```

I can write it in javascript and use the interface declaration: I("test");

But I want to do the same in Typescript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do that on classes, but you can do it with a regular function:

```
interface I {
    (name: string): void;
}

var C: I = function(name: string) {

};

C("test"); // ok
C(1);      // compile error
```

Then if you change your interface you will be notified by a compile error to change the `C` function.

Comment: What happens if you have many methods in the interface? For example:
`interface I { (name: string): void; (number: number): void; awesomeMethod(): string; }`

Answer (score 2):

Classes can't have call signatures in TypeScript.